# Xalan's SAX implementation - double encoding entities in string

Tags: java, xml

I'm using Sax with xalan implementation (v. 2.7.2). I have string in html format

```
" <p>Test k&quot;nnen</p>"
```

and I have to pass it to content of xml tag.

The result is:

```
"&lt;p&gt;Test k&amp;quot;nnen&lt;/p&gt;"
```

xalan encodes the ampersand sign although it's a part of already escaped entity.
Anyone knows a way how to make xalan understand escaped entities and not escape their ampersand?

One of possible solution is to add startCDATA() to transformerHandler but It's not something can use in my code.

```java
public class TestSax{


public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerConfigurationException, SAXException {
    TestSax t = new TestSax();

    System.out.println(t.createSAXXML());
}

public String createSAXXML() throws SAXException, TransformerConfigurationException {
    Writer writer = new StringWriter( );
    StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(writer);

    SAXTransformerFactory transformerFactory =
            (SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance( );
    String data = null;
    TransformerHandler transformerHandler =
            transformerFactory.newTransformerHandler( );

    transformerHandler.setResult(streamResult);
    transformerHandler.startDocument( );
    transformerHandler.startElement(null,"decimal","decimal", null);

    data = " <p>Test k&quot;nnen</p>";
    transformerHandler.characters(data.toCharArray(),0,data.length( ));
    transformerHandler.endElement(null,"decimal","decimal");
    transformerHandler.endDocument( );

    return writer.toString( );
}}
```

Comment: Consider to show minimal but complete code samples of your Java, XML and XSLT code allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added my code, look at edited post.

Comment: Yes you're passed your data as a String with characters. Can't you use `startElement` / `endElement` for the `<p>` tag?

Comment: No, this tag comes from client's side. I can't modify this.

Comment: If you want to treat `<p>Test k&quot;nnen</p>` as XML input to an XSLT transformation why can't you use a StreamSource over a StringReader?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? How will this fix my problem with double escaped &quot; entity?

Answer (score 1):

If your input is XML, then you need to parse it. Then `<p>` and `</p>` will be recognized as tags, and `&quot;` will be recognized as an entity reference.

On the other hand if you want to treat it as a string and pass it through XML machinery, then `"<"` and `"&"` are going to be preserved as ordinary characters, which means they will be escaped as `&lt;` and `&amp;` respectively.

If you want `"<"` treated as an ordinary character but `"&"` treated with its XML meaning, then you need software with some kind of split personality, and you're not going to get that off-the-shelf.